# hiding database password using codec specification in datasource.groovy not working

Tags: grails, groovy

I am hiding the database password in datasource.groovy by doing

```
dataSource {
pooled = true
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "root"
password = "q59YgJCdHw3dshwlsa=="
passwordEncryptionCodec = DESCodec
dbname="mydbname"
}
```

followed the artilce : http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3620

I run the groovy codec class separately to get the encrypted string like this:
groovy grails-app/utils/DESCodec.groovy mypassword_string_text.

But After placing the DESCodec class in the Utility package in grails, when I try to start the server, it wont start but directly shutdown, It starts when I directly put the right password and comment out the codec and encrypted string. I am assuming it is not finding the codec class/anything else I am missing in the config like specifying the codec class requires quotes or any path change or I should change the algorithm, by the way the DESCodec class is the last codec class in the link.

I am working on getting the config to be environment specific and externalized, but I still need the password to be encrypted here, and then decrypted before connecting to the database.

Comment: I moved the Descodec class into utility/gra/reports directory, and importing the class in the datasource.groovy as import gra.reports.Descodec, its still not working..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to externalise environment specific configuration (especially passwords, but URL's, email addresses and so on too) and then protect the config file with proper permissions on the file system of the target machine.

In Config.groovy (for example):

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "file:/etc/${appName}/conf/db.properties"
]
```

and in the config file:

```
dataSource.username = "root"
dataSource.password = "secret"
```

I typically do this for production config, but keep dev/test config in the Config.groovy for convenience. When running in dev/test you simply get a warning at startup if it can't find the referenced config file.  If it does find it, then it will override what's in Config.groovy

This has the added advantage of not requiring your war file to be recompiled and redeployed if any prod environment configuration changes, you simply change the config file and restart the app.

Comment: Hi Darrend, I do accept that externalizing the variables is the way to go but I still want the password string to encrypted even in the externalized location.

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid specifing dataSource.username, dataSource.password at all in case of Oracle connections string such as "/" or "/@TWO_TASK" for Oracle Wallet?